# iOS: UIView's origin with respect to UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

A UIView has an origin contained in its frame or bounds properties with respect to its superview. Say I want to do something which grabs the origin of a UIView with respect to the UIWindow instead. Do I have to go each step up the hierarchy in order to make this calculation or is there a simpler, more direct way?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the view?  Are you talking about touch/dragging it?

Comment: I want to make a different way of showing a UIImage. Basically I want to be able to have the user tap the image, and then cause it to take over the full screen to show the image, and when the user is done, it will restore the UIView back the way it was. Does my description make sense?

Comment: You may find it easier just to create another view that spans the full screen and show the image in that view. You can work out how you want to present that view (hide/unhide or animate for example) without altering the original view or the behavior of the original view. Then you just need some code to manage this new view that is independent of the code that manages the original view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you looking for this method

[convertPoint:toView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:)

Answer (score 2):

to find out where a view `aView` is in the application window, try

[aView convertRect:aView.frame toView:[UIWindow screen]]

This method is in the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html)

Comment: note: origin - is a point(CGPoint). So, use `convertPoint` method istead

Comment: Oops! I missed that. You identified the right method. Use the form above with convertPoint rather than convertRect.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to do this is by using `convertPoint:toView` or `convertRect:toView` on `UIWindow`. In order to do this correctly, you need to supply a view whose window matches the window of the view whose coordinates you are trying to convert.

For your question, you need to know a view's origin with respect to its location in the window. Thankfully, you don't need to know the window in order to get this. According to the documentation of `UIView`'s `convert:to` methods.

> The view into whose coordinate system point is to be converted. If view is nil, this method instead converts to window base coordinates. Otherwise, both view and the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow object.

This means that you can just supply `nil` to achieve what you need!

In Swift:

`let pointInWindow = yourView.convert(.zero, to: nil)`

In Objective-C:

`CGPoint pointInWindow = [yourView convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:nil];`